# ICollection from viewModel showing up as Null and not Empty in Controller (MVC4)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following viewModel:

```
namespace Flashcard.Models
{
    public class CreateCardViewModel
    {
        [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
        public int SetId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public ICollection<Side> Sides { get; set; }

    }
}
```

I use this ViewModel against the Card Controller:

```
public class CardController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Card/

        public ActionResult Create(int setId)
        {
            var model = new CreateCardViewModel();

            var side = new Side() {Content = "Blank Side"};


            model.SetId = setId;
            model.Sides.Add(side);
            return View(model);
        }

    }
```

However when I call the Create action, I get a nullReferenceException because model.Sides is null, which does not seem to be the same as empty.  I believe I created an empty ICollection Sides in the ViewModel - why is it null in the controller?

For some context - a Card can have one or several Sides.  I'm trying to always add a Side whenever a Card is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to initiate a `Collection` and assign it to the property of your object as follows:

```
public class CardController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Card/

    public ActionResult Create(int setId)
    {
        var model = new CreateCardViewModel();

        var side = new Side() {Content = "Blank Side"};


        model.SetId = setId;


        model.Sides = new List<Side>();

        model.Sides.Add(side);
        return View(model);
    }

}
```

Your collection is null. make one and assign to your prop.